# Proving basic limit properties for convergent sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n = b$. We wish to prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n = ab$$

We are to prove this from the definition from convergent sequences. Let $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 > 0$. We have that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon_1$ and $|b_n - b| < \epsilon_2$. I have tried using some properties of absolute values to get the expression $|a_nb_n - ab| < \epsilon$, but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use this inequality
$$|a_nb_n-ab|=|a_nb_n-ab_n+ab_n-ab|\le|b_n|\cdot|a_n-a|+|a|\cdot|b_n-b|$$
and the definition of the limit of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ and notice that $(b_n)$ is convergent hence bounded.

Comment: Ah, I seem to forget the triangle inequality.

Comment: Nice answer, Sami!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $|a_nb_n-ab|$ = $|a_nb_n-a_nb+a_nb-ab|$ and then use triangle inequality. Then use the fact that $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge to $a$ and $b$ rpectively.

Comment: And the fact that convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: yeah right...i forgot to mention that.